# Dynamically choose inputs based on reactive subset data in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

*Setup:* I already have build a shiny-app with two plots. I used the `flexdashboard`-package to create two plots in two tabs. In addition I programmed the whole shiny-app in R-markdown.

*Now* I want to create an interface where the user can subset the data. That part itself works. However I also need to perform some calculations with the subsetted data, before I do my  two plots.

Is there any way I can transform some subsetted object like `mydata` to a dataframe? My problem is that I need to use this subsetted object also in the UI part of the other plots.

EDIT: I specifically need some way to transport my selection from `checkboxGroupInput` to `selectInput("cat_1","  category 1:",choices = levels(mydata()$mycat)`.

```
### 1. Create some sample data
myrows<-sample(letters,12)
exdata<- data.frame(mycat=rep(myrows,2),yr=rep(1:2,each=12),KPI_1=rnorm(24),
                    KPI_2=round(runif(24,1,20)),KPI_3=rbinom(24,6,0.5))

### 2. UI part
fluidPage(fluidRow(
  checkboxGroupInput("comp", "Categories",myrows,myrows,inline=TRUE),
  actionButton("go", "Update"),
  textOutput("txt"),
  tableOutput("head"))
)

### 3. Server part
mydata<-eventReactive(input$go,{
  res<-subset(exdata,mycat%in%input$comp)
  return(res)
  })

  output$txt <- renderText({
     paste("You chose", paste(input$comp, collapse = ", "))
   })
   output$head <- renderTable({
   mydata()
   })
```

In the next chunk I do this:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

### 4. UI part of my plot
fluidRow(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
           selectInput("cat_1",
                       "  category 1:",
                       choices = levels(mydata()$mycat),
                       selected = levels(mydata()$mycat)[1]),
           selectInput("cat_2",
                       "  category 2:",
                       choices = levels(mydata()$mycat),
                       selected = levels(mydata()$mycat)[2])),
           mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot3", height = 300, width = 700))))

  ### 5. Server part of my plot
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
  ## 5.1 Create plot data      
      cat1<-input$cat_1
      cat2<-input$cat_2
      y1<-as.numeric(mydata()[mydata()$mycat==cat1])
      y2<-as.numeric(mydata()[mydata()$mycat==cat2])
      x0<-c(1,2)

  ## 5.2 Do plot
  plot_ly(x = x0,y = y1, type="scatter",mode='lines+markers',name=Firm1) %>%
  add_trace(y = y2, name = Firm2, mode = 'lines+markers') %>%
            layout(dragmode = "select")
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue as everything is working for me. Perhaps you are not showing the entire code

Comment: oh yes. sorry. will add it in a second

Comment: Could you please update your code as it is hard to know where exactly it is fitting.  I think you can create an object in the server, store the output and update it while the action is triggered and then call that object in the selectInput

Comment: @akrun sorry for the confusion. I already did. The issue is in `selectInput("cat_1","  category 1:",choices = levels(mydata()$mycat),`. Apparently shiny doesnt like dynamic elements in its inputs. It makes sense if you want to build one plot, but not really if you build a whole dashboard

Comment: I meant the `choices = levels(mydata()$mycat)` should be changed

Comment: yes it should. The issue is that `choices` should be dependent on what I choose in `checkboxGroupInput`. Basically I want it to be equal to `input$comp`. I though if I put input in an reactive conductor it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out your code. So:

1) Make use of `renderUI` which will allow you to dynamically create controls

2) Stick with one `ui`

3) Make sure you understand the `renderPlotly` and what you're trying to plot

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

### 1. Create some sample data
myrows<-sample(letters,12)
exdata<- data.frame(mycat=rep(myrows,2),yr=rep(1:2,each=12),KPI_1=rnorm(24),
                    KPI_2=round(runif(24,1,20)),KPI_3=rbinom(24,6,0.5))


ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("c1"),uiOutput("c2")),
  mainPanel(
    column(6,
    checkboxGroupInput("comp", "Categories",myrows,myrows,inline=TRUE),
    actionButton("go", "Update"),
    textOutput("txt"),
    tableOutput("head")),
    column(6,
    plotlyOutput("plot3", height = 300, width = 700)))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  ### 3. Server part
  mydata <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    res<-subset(exdata,mycat%in%input$comp)
    return(res)
  })

  output$txt <- renderText({
    paste("You chose", paste(input$comp, collapse = ", "))
  })
  output$head <- renderTable({
    mydata()
  })

  conrolsdata <- reactive({
    unique(as.character(mydata()$mycat))
  })
  output$c1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("cat_1", "Variable:",conrolsdata())
  })

  output$c2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("cat_2", "Variable:",conrolsdata())
  })


  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({

    if(is.null(input$cat_1)){
      return()
    }

    y1<- mydata()$KPI_1[as.character(mydata()$mycat) %in% input$cat_1]
    y2<- mydata()$KPI_2[as.character(mydata()$mycat) %in% input$cat_2]
    x0<-c(1,2)
     #use the key aesthetic/argument to help uniquely identify selected observations
     plot_ly(x = x0,y = y1, type="scatter",mode='lines+markers',name="Firm1") %>%
       add_trace(y = y2, name = "Firm2", mode = 'lines+markers') %>%
       layout(dragmode = "select")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The main reason for the weird code was the use of `flexdashboard` and R-markdown. Given my experience so far I recommend everyone who runs into issues while using `flexdashboard`, to try (re-)creating your app in `shiny`. It might solve some issues. 

Very nice to learn how to apply `renderUI`, somehow my refresher on `shiny` didnt mention that.